# IBM Worklight - Form validation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, ibm-mobilefirst

How can i validate form elements using jQuery Validation, i.e `.validate()`.
I Have the following code:

```
$('#form1').validate({

});
```

I want check that the username and password should not be empty,
New password and re-enter password should match, and etc.

Comment: is it possible to call jquery Mobile validation using IBM Worklight

Comment: that example on serverside validation..want validation using Jquery is it possible

Comment: What are you trying to validate? that the username input is correct (using only letters, etc...) or that the value of the username is correct?

Comment: i want check username and password should not be empty. new password and reenter password sould match and e.tc

Comment: Idan I wrote Jquery Validate but it shows $(..).validate() is not a function in worklight.js file in IBM Worklight

Comment: What is this "validate"? Are you using a plug-in? from where?

Comment: its jquery Mobile Plugin.. is there any way to front end validate in worklight hybrid app form elements like front end validation in web application using javascript/jquery

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/.. do u have any example on hybrid app with form validation in worklight

Comment: i downloaded stable version in that site..and extracted into a folder..when i am creating a hybrid app along with by selecting javascript libarary  to extracted folder and in html file usibg script tag those .js included

Comment: You're getting errors because the `.validate()` method is neither part of jQuery Mobile or jQuery. [The jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) needs to be included if you want to use the `.validate()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MobileFirst Platform 6.3, the code from Sukima's answer worked just fine for me, with the following setup-related changes:

1. Downloaded [jQuery Validation plug-in](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/jquery-validation-1.13.1.zip)
2. Copied `plug-in-folder\dist\jquery.validate.js` to `my-project\apps\my-app\common\js`
3. Added to common\index.html's HEAD:

   ```
   ...
   ...
   <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
   ```
4. In common\index.html's BODY:

   ```
   <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
       <fieldset>
           <legend>Please provide your name.</legend>
          <p>
              <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
              <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>
          </p>
          <p>
              <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
          </p>
       </fieldset>
    </form>
   ```
5. In common\js\main.js:

   ```
   function wlCommonInit(){
       $('#commentForm').validate({
           submitHandler: function() {
               alert('Fake Submit');
           }
       });
   }
   ```
6. Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server
7. Opened MobileFirst Console > preview common web resources

Tried with 1 or 3 characters; validation worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your asking the wrong question. Simply put (based on the context provided by the question) that you have not read and/or understood the documentation. The [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) uses the HTML attributes you provided for the form elements to perform it's own validation. So if your markup is correct then your `.validate()` should work.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#commentForm').validate({
    submitHandler: function() {
      alert('Fake Submit');
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name.</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
      <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

See [jQuery Validation Plugin Documentation for more examples](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/).

Comment: i wrote above code in .js file when submit button clicked.. but it showing $(..).validate() is not a function in worklight.js file in IBM Worklight

Comment: @LingaReddy, see my answer above.

Comment: You're correct that the OP misunderstood something.  Based on the wording, I don't think the OP realizes that `.validate()` is provided by the jQuery Validate plugin and not already built into jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Usually a good indication when the jQuery API docs don't include it. I find it easier to RTFM then to post on SO; hence why I assumed the OP had done his/her homework. Oh Well, back to fun coding...